# jQuery change element without changing its children

Tags: jquery

I want to create an open menu that when I click once on the li it opens and show me the other li's, but i don't want that on click on the li's that opened (the children li's) it will close. i want it to do nothing.
so I want to pick the li parents but not its children that are also li.
this is the code and a solution that I tried but didn't work.

```
        <ul>
            <li class="only">1dkhg
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrRT0M-NSrnnPJrKSF3YtyJGtSXjcBQHuuql5vp-cUYEx-j-F8">
                <ul>
                    <li class="no">1kldg</li>
                    <li class="no">2kldg</li>
                    <li class="no">3kldg</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

and the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".only:not('.no')").click(function() {
        $( this ).find('ul').animate({
            height: "toggle"
         });
        $(this).find('img').toggleClass('click');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
$(".only").click(function (e) {
        if(e.target !== this) return;
        $(this).find('ul').animate({
            height: "toggle"
        });
        $(this).find('img').toggleClass('click');
    });
```

Comment: Checking that the target is the bound element is the way to go IMO, +1 !

Answer (score 1):

A better structure would be to use an `anchor` in the root `li` so that when you click the anchor, the child `ul` opens. This way you can avoid worrying about event bubbling, and it's more semantically accurate to describe a click target:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Anchor</a>
    <ul>
      <li>sub anchors</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#nav>li>a').click(function(e){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```